# SQL Server stored procedure with WHERE clause logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table of results in my application and a box that allows a user to filter the result set by one or more values.

I had to add an **optional** `needBy` date to the records so that a person could specify if they need the request to be handled by a certain date.

The part I am struggling with is the filtering of the optional date structure. My filters are as follows:

- Current = All requests that have a need by date less than or equal to today
- Future = All requests with a need by date that is greater than today
- All = All requests both with and without a need by date

Here is an example of my query. The `WHERE` for everything expect the `@needBy` is working just fine.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    (@requestor IS NULL OR r.Requestor = @requestor) 
    AND
    (@user IS NULL OR t.QID = @user)
    AND
    (@tool IS NULL OR t.ToolID = @tool)
    AND
    (@role IS NULL OR t.RoleID = @role)
    AND
    (@action IS NULL OR t.ActionID = @action)
    AND
    (@status IS NULL OR t.StatusID = @status)
    AND
    (@needBy IS NULL OR CASE 
                            WHEN @needBy = 'current' THEN r.NeedByDate <= GETUTCDATE()
                            WHEN @needBy = 'future' THEN r.NeedByDate > GETUTCDATE()
                            WHEN @needBy = 'all' THEN r.NeedByDate IS NOT NULL
                        END)
```

How should I approach this query differently for the dates? The one additional problem is `@needBy = 'all'`. In this situation, I need all records, regardless of it having a date in the future, in the past, or provided at all.

In my code above, it seems to not like the logic operators that are inside of the `WHEN/THEN` statement.

Comment: The THEN part of a CASE expression cannot encapsulate logic.   It can only return a value.

Comment: Gail Shaw has an excellent blog about this type of query. https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/ She also references a very important article on the topic by Erland Sommarskog. Well worth reading both articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You started good with the `OR` conditions, you just need to go all the way:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    TABLE
WHERE 
    (@requestor IS NULL OR r.Requestor = @requestor) 
    AND
    (@user IS NULL OR t.QID = @user)
    AND
    (@tool IS NULL OR t.ToolID = @tool)
    AND
    (@role IS NULL OR t.RoleID = @role)
    AND
    (@action IS NULL OR t.ActionID = @action)
    AND
    (@status IS NULL OR t.StatusID = @status)
    AND
    (@needBy IS NULL OR 
         (@needBy = 'current' AND r.NeedByDate <= GETUTCDATE()) OR 
         (@needBy = 'future'  AND r.NeedByDate > GETUTCDATE()) OR 
         (@needBy = 'all' AND r.NeedByDate IS NOT NULL)
     )
```

Please note that catch-all queries often suffer from inefficient execution plan, since it's compiled based on a set of parameters that might not be the best for the next set of parameters.
One solution for that would be to add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` to the stored procedure.
For more information, Please refer to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `CASE`:

```
 (@needBy IS NULL OR 
   ( @needBy = 'current' AND r.NeedByDate <= GETUTCDATE() )
   OR 
   ( @needBy = 'future' AND r.NeedByDate > GETUTCDATE() )
   OR 
   ( @needBy = 'all' AND r.NeedByDate IS NOT NULL )
                       )
```